# Переход по сайтам из списка (массива) на PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Есть, например, 5 сайтов в списке и мне нужно автоматом их просмотреть, дождаться загрузки первого и только потом переходить ко второму. Если у кого есть хотя бы похожий код, поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так, сами уже допилите под ваши нужды

```
$sates = array('сайт1','сайт2','сайт3');
for($i=0; $i=count($sates)-1; $i++)
 {
   file_get_contents($sates[$i]);
   sleep(3); 
 }
```

Comment: а sllep зачем?

Answer (score 2):

```
$sites=array('url1','url2','url3','url4','url5');
foreach($sites as $site){
echo file_get_contents($site);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на curl, позволяет расширить настройки:

```
$file = file('link.txt');
$referer = 'yandex.ru';
$header[] = "Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: Windows-1251, utf-8, *;q=0.1";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: deflate, identity, *;q=0";

foreach ($file as $key => $link) {

    //curl сессия
    $user_cookie = "cookies.txt";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $user_cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $user_cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //выводим результат в браузер
    echo $result;

    unlink("cookies.txt");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

*file_get_contents(site)* не сработает для защищенных протоколов! Например, таких, как **HTTPS**.
Чтобы получить контент сайта с любыми протоколами, надо использовать cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  //SSL для https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Данный код выведет содержимое страницы, привязанной к любому протоколу.